# How to detect that emacs is in terminal-mode?

Tags: emacs, configuration, terminal

In my `.emacs` file, I have commands that only makes sense in graphical mode (like `(set-frame-size (selected-frame) 166 100)`). How do I run these only in graphical mode and not in terminal mode (i.e. `emacs -nw`).

Thanks!

Answer (score 117, accepted):

The `window-system` variable tells Lisp programs what window system Emacs is running under. The possible values are

**x**

Emacs is displaying the frame using X.

**w32**

Emacs is displaying the frame using native MS-Windows GUI.

**ns**

Emacs is displaying the frame using the Nextstep interface (used on GNUstep and Mac OS X).

**pc**

Emacs is displaying the frame using MS-DOS direct screen writes.

**nil**

Emacs is displaying the frame on a character-based terminal.

From [the doc](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Window-Systems.html).

**Edit**: it seems that window-system is deprecated in favor of `display-graphic-p` (source: C-h f window-system RET on emacs 23.3.1).

```
(display-graphic-p &optional DISPLAY)

Return non-nil if DISPLAY is a graphic display.
Graphical displays are those which are capable of displaying several
frames and several different fonts at once.  This is true for displays
that use a window system such as X, and false for text-only terminals.
DISPLAY can be a display name, a frame, or nil (meaning the selected
frame's display).
```

So what you want to do is :

```
(if (display-graphic-p)
    (progn
    ;; if graphic
      (your)
      (code))
    ;; else (optional)
    (your)
    (code))
```

And if you don't have an else clause, you can just:

```
;; more readable :)
(when (display-graphic-p)
    (your)
    (code))
```

Comment: (window-system)  == "ns"    on my mac

Answer (score 47):

The answers mentioning `window-system` and `display-graphic-p` aren't wrong, but they don't tell the complete picture.

In reality, a single Emacs instance can have multiple frames, some of which might be on a terminal, and others of which might be on a window system. That is to say, you can get different values of `window-system` even within a single Emacs instance.

For example, you can start a window-system Emacs and then connect to it via `emacsclient -t` in a terminal; the resulting terminal frame will see a value of `nil` for `window-system`. Similarly, you can start emacs in daemon mode, then later tell it to create a graphical frame.

As a result of this, avoid putting code in your .emacs that depends on `window-system`. Instead, put code like your `set-frame-size` example in a hook function which runs after a frame is created:

```
(add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions
  (lambda (frame)
    (with-selected-frame frame
      (if window-system
        (set-frame-size frame 166 100))))))
```

Note that the `'after-make-frame-functions` hook isn't run for the initial frame, so it's often necessary to also add frame-related hook functions like that above to `'after-init-hook`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not clear on the terminology, but if I run (split-window-horizontally), does that create a new frame and thus invoke this? Or does this only run when creating an entirely new window attached to this instance (like by using emacsclient)?

Comment: The Emacs terminology uses "frame" to mean what you would normally call a "window", and it uses "window" to denote what you would normally call a "pane". Confusing, but you get used to it eventually. Hope that helps. :-)

Comment: And, to answer your question explicitly: `split-window-horizontally` splits the currently-active pane ("window") in the current window ("frame") into two panes ("windows").

Comment: This will not work since: after-make-frame-functions is run after the frame is created. This doesn't apply to the initial emacs frame (on startup) because your .emacs is read after the frame is already created.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/875667/how-do-i-run-a-command-just-after-the-emacs-frame-has-been-rendered

Comment: @Rubycut agreed. I should have mentioned that it's often necessary to add frame-related hook functions like that to `'after-init-hook`.

Answer (score 8):

> window-system is a variable defined in
>   `C source code'. Its value is x
>
> Documentation: Name of window system
>   through which the selected frame is
>   displayed. The value is a symbol--for
>   instance, `x' for X windows. The value
>   is nil if the selected frame is on a
>   text-only-terminal.

Basically do a:

```
(if window-system
    (progn
      (something)
      (something-else)))
```

Comment: deprecated in favor of display-graphic-p

Answer (score 6):

If its in Gui mode, then the following would be true.

(if window-system )

Answer (score 2):

I have defined an extra function to wrap the window-name functionality because I'm using Emacs everywhere, i.e. from the terminal and in graphics mode and in Linux and MacOS:

```
(defun window-system-name()
  (cond ((eq system-type 'gnu/linux) (if (display-graphic-p) "x"   "nox"))
    ((eq system-type 'darwin)    (if (display-graphic-p) "mac" "nox"))
    (t (error "Unsupported window-system") nil)))
```

It can be extended to cover other systems like Windows or older systems where a serial terminal is used. But I Have no time to do so ;-)