# How to check if Xorg is running in emacs lisp?

Tags: linux, emacs, lisp, elisp, xorg

I've got some things in my configuration that works only in Xorg else dropping errors.

To solve it I need to know if Xorg is running or not. How can I check it ?

```
(defun nCdy-mode ()
    ;; TOOD: Add Xorg check
    ;(tool-bar-mode nil)
    (menu-bar-mode nil) ; TODO: Add hotkey
    ;(scroll-bar-mode nil)
    (setq inhibit-splash-screen t)

    (setq standard-indent 4)
    ;;(mouse-wheel-mode t)
    (setq backup-directory-alist (quote ((".*" . "~/.emacs_backups/"))))

    ;;TODO: Add Xorg check
    ;(require 'nyan-mode)
    ;(nyan-mode)
    ;(nyan-start-animation)
    ;;nyanyanyanyanyanyanyanyanyanyan
```

*thank you*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
(case window-system
  (x '"X11 running")
  (otherwise "No X11"))
```

Answer (score 4):

While Jürgen is correct that you probably want to test the value of `window-system`, note that because of its client/server mechanism, a single Emacs instance can have several frames, some of which are on graphic terminals (e.g. XOrg) and some of which are in text terminals.

As a result, you should think about where and when to test for `window-system`. See [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795451/how-to-detect-that-emacs-is-in-terminal-mode/5801740#5801740) for more on how to deal with that.