# Launching eshell when starting up emacs from terminal with cwd

Tags: emacs, terminal, eshell

I added a hook to my *init.el* to launch Emacs on eshell.

```
;;start on eshell
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook 'eshell)
```

The thing is, I often launch Emacs from the terminal and would love to have eshell working directory being the working directory of the terminal from which I launched Emacs.

Let's say I'm in a directory X, and launch Emacs

```
~/X $ emacs
```

I want this to happen

```
Welcome to the Emacs shell
~/X $
```

For now, I have added

```
(cd "~")
```

to my *init.el*, as a temporary solution (changes emacs path to home), but it's not good enough.

**Edit**

I want to run Emacs in its gui.

**Edit 2**

Chris's answer worked if not using `open -a emacs` to launch the application. But just with the executable path instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can detect that Emacs is running in a terminal when the function `display-graphic-p` returns `nil`, and you can get the directory from which you invoked Emacs from the `default-directory` variable.

So something like

```lisp
(when (not (display-graphic-p))
  (cd default-directory)
  (eshell))
```

in your init should change to the "current" directory and then launch `eshell` when Emacs is invoked from the terminal.

If you always wish to invoke `eshell` you should be able to remove `(eshell)` from the code and simply keep your `emacs-startup-hook`.

**Edit:** Replaced variable `window-system` with call to function `display-graphic-p` as recommended in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5795518/354577).

**Edit 2:** If you simply want to modify your `emacs-startup-hook` to change to whatever directory you invoke Emacs from and then launch `eshell` (regardless of the windowing system), you can use something like

```lisp
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook
          (lambda ()
            (cd default-directory)
            (eshell)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input Chris. But I want to run emacs with its gui actually. Sorry for being unclear about that. I tried with only (cd default-directory) but it didn't work, as I sadly expected..

Comment: @FelixD., I must have been confused by "launch Emacs from the terminal". I have updated my answer to show how to use an anonymous function in your `emacs-startup-hook` that should do what you want.

Comment: Thank you, but it's still not working. Could it be due to my terminal function that calls emacs? http://i61.tinypic.com/30abaqb.png , but I doubt it..

Comment: @FelixD., possibly, I don't have a Mac to test on. If you run Emacs using `/path/to/your/Emacs.app` instead of using your shell wrapper, does it behave as expected?

Comment: yes thanks!! I'll guess I'll have to fix that. The problem is, oddly, when I open emacs the "classic way", the terminal seems to be pending while Emacs is active. With open -a emacs instead, the terminal acts normally and gives me a new prompt right after opening emacs.

Comment: @FelixD., glad you got it working. You can probably update your wrapper to include something like `--chdir $(pwd)` as an argument to Emacs, which should make your `open`ed Emacs respect your working directory.

Comment: Thanks! It doesn't work for now but I will overcome that fast enough!