# How can I hide the menu bar from a specific frame in emacs?

Tags: emacs

I have emacs setup to start as daemon on login (`emacs --daemon`). When editing files I either launch the graphical client (`emacsclient`) or when I'm working in the terminal, I use the terminal client (`emacsclient -t`).

I want to have the menu bar enabled in the graphical client, but I don't want to have it in the terminal client, because I don't like its behavior in the terminal.

The menu bar can be enable/disabled via `menu-bar-mode`, but it behaves as the help says:

> This command applies to all frames that exist and frames to be created in the future.

This means, when I have a graphical client running and I start a terminal client, the terminal client shows the menu bar and when I disable it, it is also disabled in the graphical client.

How can I hide the menu bar from a frame specifically? Is there a frame-local setting for the menu bar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the [frame parameter](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Layout-Parameters.html#Layout-Parameters) for `menu-bar-lines` to 1 if on a graphical display, and 0 if in a terminal, as checked by `(display-graphic-p)`:

```
(defun contextual-menubar (&optional frame)
  "Display the menubar in FRAME (default: selected frame) if on a
graphical display, but hide it if in terminal."
  (interactive)
  (set-frame-parameter frame 'menu-bar-lines (if (display-graphic-p frame) 1 0)))
```

You can `(add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions 'contextual-menubar)` to make it automatic.  According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795451/how-to-detect-that-emacs-is-in-terminal-mode), `after-make-frame-functions` is not run for the initial frame, so you may need to add it to `after-init-hook` as well.

Comment: It works! Thank you. Do you think it's worth reporting or asking to make `mode-menu-bar` frame-local or doesn't the mode (like menu-bar-mode is) concept allow for this? It looks more like a workaround by simply removing the area for the menu bar to draw in.

Comment: Up to you.  Actually, if you dig into the source code for `menu-bar-mode`, it turns out that it's basically doing the same `(set-frame-parameter ...)`, just on all frames, to add/remove the area for the menu bar.  The code itself is pretty short, so it would probably not be hard to add the functionality you're thinking about.